# Query for two table JOIN operation

Tags: oracle11g

**Table:1**

```
EMP_ID      DEPT    BATCH_CODE      DEP_CODE
1234        IT          B4            D1
4567        DESIGN      B5            D2
1232        MARKETING   B6            D3
```

<sub>`EMP_ID` is PK in Table1</sub>

**Table:2**

```
CODE        DESCRITPION
B4           IT DEVELOPMENT
D1           TECHNICAL DESING
B5           SUPPORT
D2           DB DESIGNER
B6           SALES
D3           CASH
```

**Expected Output**

```
BATCH CODE      Batch Description   Dep_Code    Dep_Descritpion
B4                IT DEVELOPMENT     D1          TECHNICAL DESING
B5                SUPPORT            D2          DB DESIGNER
B6                SALES              D3          CASH
```

Could anyone help me out to structure a query to get the expected output from table1 and table2 values?

Comment: Have you made any effort yet.. If so post your attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
select b.CODE BATCH_CODE,b.Description BATCH_Description,
  c.code Dep_Code,c.Description Dep_Descritpion
from table1 a
join table2 b on a.BATCH_CODE=b.CODE
join table2 c on a.DEP_CODE=c.CODE
```